# How to use more files as input?

Tags: awk

What is wrong with this file please? I would like to print minima of 70 files into file min. Thank you

```
awk 'BEGIN{a=100000}{if ($1<0+a) a=$1} END{print a}' file[01-70].asc > min
```

Comment: You mean minimum of $1 value in 70 files right? If this is the case then why are you comparing them with `a=100000`?

Comment: Your question reads like if you took your car to a mechanic and said "What is wrong with this car please? I would like to drive it to work" instead of telling your mechanic anything about the problems you've been having with your car that led you to bring the car to her. Tell us what problems you're having (wrong output, no output, error messages, core dumps, etc.) and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output that can be used to reproduce your problem and test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{min=min<=$1?(min!=""?min:$1):$1} END{print min}' file{01..70}.asc
```

If happy with results then redirect its output to `>  min` as per your shown code too. Fair warning this code is not tested since no samples were given in your post.

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation to above code.

```
awk '                            ##Starting awk program from here.
{                                ##Starting main BLOCK from here.
 min=min<=$1?(min!=""?min:$1):$1 ##Creating a variable min where checking if min value is NULL then assign it to $1 OR min is greater than $1 then assign it as $1 or keep it as it is.
}                                ##Closing main block here.
END{                             ##Starting END section of this program here.
  print min                      ##Printing min variable value here.
}
' file{01..70}.asc               ##Mentioning Input_file(s) names by file01 to file70.asc
```

Comment: `awk: fatal: cannot open file `file[01-70].asc' for reading (No such file or directory)` Files are names as file00001, file00002 ..... file00010 ....

Comment: @Arrara, Please try my edited code once and let me know I changed it to `file{01..70}.asc`.

Comment: Thank you, it works and how to print minimum from each file? I mean that input will be 70 rows.

Comment: @Arrara, change `END` to `ENDFILE` in my code and let me know then?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to list the files from 01 to 70, but `[01-70]` is not one of them.  Consider:

```
$ echo file{01..10}.asc
file1.asc file2.asc file3.asc file4.asc file5.asc file6.asc file7.asc file8.asc file9.asc file10.asc
$ for i in $(seq -w 10); do touch file$i.asc; done
$ ls 
file01.asc  file02.asc  file03.asc  file04.asc  file05.asc  file06.asc  file07.asc  file08.asc  file09.asc  file10.asc
$ ls file*.asc
file01.asc  file02.asc  file03.asc  file04.asc  file05.asc  file06.asc  file07.asc  file08.asc  file09.asc  file10.asc
$ ls file{10,0{1..9}}.asc
file01.asc  file02.asc  file03.asc  file04.asc  file05.asc  file06.asc  file07.asc  file08.asc  file09.asc  file10.asc
$ ls file[01-10].asc
ls: file[01-10].asc: No such file or directory
$ echo file[01-10].asc
file[01-10].asc
```

In short, you probably just want to use `awk ... file0{1..9}.asc file{10..70}.asc` or `file[01234567][0123456789].asc` or `file[01234567][[:digit:]].asc`, but you may be able to simply use `file*.asc`

Comment: In bash you can use `file{0001..0070}.asc` to format the leading zeros.

Comment: In bash 4, that expansion works, but not in 3.2. :(

Answer (score 2):

Correct is to use `END` and not `ENDFILE` as I did write, so OPs solution should work.

```
cat f1
10
1

cat f2
20
2

cat f3
30
3
```

```
awk '{f+=$1} ENDFILE {print FILENAME,"ENDFILE="f} END {print "All file END="f}' f[1-3]
f1 ENDFILE=11
f2 ENDFILE=33
f3 ENDFILE=66
All file END=66
```

`ENDFILE` is run at end of each file
`END` is run after all file has been read.

Comment: I was going through `man awk` of Ubuntu's GNU `awk` 4.1 version and found following. `BEGINFILE  and  ENDFILE are additional special patterns whose bodies are executed before reading the first record of each command line input file and after
       reading the last record of each file.` Even I tested with sample files it prints minimum number by using `ENDFILE` after end of each file. I apologies  if I missed something, just want to be clear on this one.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I did see that I did an error and updated my post.